# Fighting with UITableView size and NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a Container View which lives on the left side of the main UIViewConroller. This container view is constructed of a few buttons at the bottom, a UITableView in the middle to show user data, and another UITableView at the top to display *selected* user data. I want the behavior of the this top UITableView such that it disappears if there is no selected data and reaches a max height of 200 if there is. Each data item selected will equate to an entry in the table.

Check out the pics. In the pic where it is running, I have loaded one selected data item titled "test":

[image]
[image]

Anyhow, the problem I am having is related to the layout constraints that are created by Interface Builder. Here are the steps I have taken to dynamically re-size the data table, and selected data table.

I have set the top most TableView to be <= 200, left the middle one as default, and then added this code to do the resizing of the top table:

```
-(void)setSelectedFacets:(NSArray *)selectedFacets{
    _selectedFacets = selectedFacets;
    [self.selectedFacetsTableView reloadData];

    CGRect frame = self.selectedFacetsTableView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 10 ;//36 * selectedFacets.count;
    self.selectedFacetsTableView.frame = frame;
    [self.selectedFacetsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The above code snipped does execute (after the view controller is fully loaded), but has no effect on the actual hieght.

Does anyone have any experience wit this?

I know that you can add an IBOutlet to the NSLayoutConstraints (to get a reference to them) then delete them at run time. This seems like more work than it should be. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set a frame if you're using autolayout. Only add/remove/modify layout constraints.

Make sure you're using only NSLayoutConstraints in IB by using the "Pin" and "Align" etc. buttons. Make the constraint for the tableView height accessible in the source code:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableViewHeightConstraint;`

The snippet to actually set the height should be in `updateViewContraints`

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints {
    CGFloat height = MAX(200.0f, 36.0f * selectedFacets.count);
    [self.tableView removeConstraint:self.tableViewHeightConstraint];
    NSLayoutConstraint *lc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0 constant:height];
    [self.tableView addConstraint:lc];
    self.tableViewHeightConstraint = lc;
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

In `setSelectedFacets:` just call `[self updateViewConstraints]`